# Trying to get 3 divs next to each other while at the same time keeping them responsive so the stack underneath each other

Tags: html, css

Hello, as the titel already says im trying to get 3 divs next to each other while keeping them responsive, in this case if the screen decreases in size it will try to stack itself which works but the problem is that the background color of the box its in wont continue, it still thinks it just 1 row, while there are actually 3 underneath each other, if it isnt entirely clear here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsqxn1fy/

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
#darkbluebox {
  background-color: #151723;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 100px 0px;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 45px;
  background-color: #04040E;
  width: 75%;
  /* 960 / 70% */
  clear: both;
}
#textarea {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  color: #ECECEC;
}
#websites {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 65.2%;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: 270px;
}
#imagebox {
  position: relative;
  height: 220px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#JekerpmcK {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#BuenaVistaK {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#OAA {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#TekstvakK {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="darkbluebox">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="textarea">
      <h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed.</p><br><br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sedadipiscing elit sed.</p></h1>

    </div>
    <div id="websites">
      <div id="imagebox">
        <div id="JekerpmcK">

        </div>
        <div id="TekstvakK">
          JekerPMC
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="imagebox">
        <div id="BuenaVistaK">

        </div>
        <div id="TekstvakK">
          BuenaVistaHoliday
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="imagebox">
        <div id="OAA">
          Under construction!
        </div>
        <div id="TekstvakK">
          OAA Consultancy
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

So whats ment to happen is when the site realizes that it cant fit all 3 next to each other it will stack them underneath each other and at the same time make the darkbluebox higher.

I've read on some places this might be case where I need to clear something but I dont quite now how and where, so all help would be appreciated

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#container` will probably do the trick, you basically need to clear the floated `div`s.

Answer (score 3):

As hidden Hobbes commented adding overflow:hidden to container fix your problem but often when I had same problem I coudn't use that solution (as the overflow may be needed visible or auto for different purposes.

I often find that it's much better solutions to add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

in the html under your last floating div: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsqxn1fy/4/)**

Or if you prefer You may add this code on your CSS (same solution but insteed of using a div you use pseudoelement "after"). This solution has bit less compatibility support with old browsers.

```
#container:after {
    content:' ';
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsqxn1fy/5/)**

Comment: +1 Clearing float is so underrated. If used properly, it can easily resolve most of the UI hassle that comes along with floating divs.

Comment: I absolutely agree with You, The headaches I had with overflow:hidden in the past were so many. The "after" solution is what I use mainly these days (unless I am unfortunate enough to have a client asking windows xp compatilbility for his web.. of courser under explorer)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, its what they say, you often overlook the simplest solutions, I kinda made it work with @media screen but it was quite clunky so I'm really glas you guys came along. since Im kinda new here do I need to flag it somewhere to let people know its answered?

Comment: Yes pleaseJorrit. If this answer is valid I would apreciated if You mark it as so. Ty